# How to read data from mysql using next and previous buttons in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a database. It has two columns.one is `'datetime'`, second is `'data'`. The database updates for every second on real time.
I have to read database using next and previous buttons for every one minute.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select data from My_Database WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) <= datetime");
```

Initially data read with above.
How to read with next and previous buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [limit clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) to your query

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LIMIT` clause. The first 0 says starting rows from 0 (being the first row) and the 10 says read 10 rows. You will need to implement a paging logic in your php code to increase the offset every time page increase. so the next page would have offset 10 and 10 rows. LIMIT 10,10

```
"select data from My_Database WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) <= datetime LIMIT 0,10"
```

Comment: Thank you, the data adds every second to database. The first position is always varying.if i read with LIMIT 10,10 the user may get same data if he click forward button after 10 seconds.

Comment: then you introduce a auto_increment field and record the last MAX(id) and use that in the where clause also

Comment: i am trying in another way, "select data from My_Database WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN '$Category' AND '$Subcategory'"   here $Category="2013-07-08 07:56:00";
$Subcategory="2013-07-08 07:59:59"; i am getting data between that interval,i dont understood how to make function for those variables.